# Get time that is closest in csv

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a large csv file which looks like this:

```
Name address phone time
Abc. .Texas.  123   11/5/2020 4:35
Abc. .Texas.  123    7/25/2021 4:48
DEF. .Virginia.345.  3/31/2020 13:26
DEF. .VIrginia. 345.  2/24/202214:34
```

I want unique value based on name but the time needs to be closest from todays date.

What i want.

```
Name address phone time
Abc.    .Texas.    123    7/25/2021 4:48
DEF.     VIrginia. 345.   2/24/202214:34
```

My code:

```
Import-csv <file> | sort-object | Get-Unique | sort{(get-date $_.Time) | select -fist 1
```

Comment: take a look at the `Group-Object` cmdlet. you can group by Name and then sort by the date to get the newest one. ///// also, do you REALLY need this for both ps3 & ps4? both are obsolete ... so you otta not reference them unless you NEED them.

Answer (score 0):

Given you current csv, you can use `Sort-Object` to get the values you're after using a *scriptblock* for the *datetime* conversion to sort by that. Then, you can sort by name using another `Sort-Object` with a switch for `-Unique` to get the unique values of your name property:

```
@"
Name, address, phone, time
Abc, Texas, 123, 11/5/2020 4:35
Abc, Texas, 123, 7/25/2021 4:48
DEF, Virginia,345, 3/31/2020 13:26
DEF, VIrginia, 345, 2/24/2022 14:34
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
    Sort-Object -Property {[datetime]$_.Time} -Descending | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique
```

---

*...I use 2 `Sort-Object`'s because, frankly, I wasn't able to get it to work using just one, with the `-Unique` switch.*

Comment: this is what i got “cannot convert null to type system.datetime”

Comment: that means your time in your csv isn't in correct format. Can you post a sanitized version of your actual csv. Also, what PowerShell version are you using, 3.0, or 4.0?